# Прочтение результата матча

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно прочитать **5:2**, если я говорю о том, что команда победила другую команду  со счетом 5:2?

Answer (score 4):

Команда "А" победила команду "Б" со счётом 5:2.
Читаем так: со счётом пять два [без пауз].

Хорошо известный [пример](https://music-facts.ru/song/CHayf/Argentina-YAmayka_50/):

*Какая боль, какая боль,

Аргентина — Ямайка — 5:0.*

Произносим так: Аргентина Ямайка [пауза] пять ноль.
Прослушать можно [здесь](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=22KlRhN2ZCc).

[Спортивная типографика](https://www.sports.ru/tribuna/blogs/sportsidentity/679189.html) — полезная информация о пунктуации, заголовках, таблицах.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку! Прослушал с удовольствием.)