# Как записывается спортивный счёт?

Tags: оформление-текста, пробелы, цифры

Скажите, пожалуйста, как записывать счёт матча (спортивный счёт)? 4:0? 4 : 0? 4: 0? И как звучит соответствующее правило/рекомендация, где можно уточнить это?

"Грамота.ру" почему-то дала противоречивый ответ на схожий вопрос (см. [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=229794)):

**Вопрос № 229794**

> Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно указывать счет состоявшегося матча. 1) Матч закончился победой команды "Светлячки" со счетом 67:59. 2) Только что завершился матч между командами "Светлячки" и "Темные". Финальный счет встречи - 67:59. 3) Матч закончился вничью 5:5. Счет по периодам: 1:3 2:3 5:5. Есть ли ошибки в этих предложениях?

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> 1, 2. Вы написали верно, но нужно писать с пробелами: *67 : 59*. 3. Корректно: _Матч закончился вничью -- 5:5. Счет по периодам: 1 : 3, 2 : 3, 5 : 5.

Не пойму их: почему 67 : 59 (с пробелами), но 5:5 (без пробелов), при этом 1 : 3 (снова с пробелами)... Может, они опечатались? Не могу до них достучаться, а разобраться надо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. [Суперсерия СССР — Канада (1972)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%A1%D0%A1%D0%A1%D0%A0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0_(1972)):

   ```
                     3 : 4  
            СССР               Канада
                (2:2, 0:0, 1:2)
   ```
2. [БРЭ](https://bigenc.ru/sport/text/1925922) (ВОЛЕЙБО́Л):

> За ка­ж­дый вы­иг­ран­ный ро­зы­грыш на­чис­ля­ет­ся оч­ко; пар­тия про­дол­жа­ет­ся до на­бо­ра од­ной из ко­манд 25 оч­ков (в 5-й пар­тии до 15), при счё­те **24:24** (в 5-й пар­тии — **14:14**) — до пре­иму­ще­ст­ва в 2 оч­ка.

3. [Энциклопедия футбола](https://books.google.ee/books?id=t8jcDgAAQBAJ&pg=PA99&lpg=PA99&dq=%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%87%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%205-%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE.%20%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%E2%80%95%20%D0%93%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%E2%80%95%205:%200.%20%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%87%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%207-%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE&source=bl&ots=QKqmT8mqEr&sig=ACfU3U1PnVeuPZzSVIsRe3f5SHxziWT54Q&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiMsYeHx9v6AhVB6CoKHfKyAqIQ6AF6BAgVEAM#v=onepage&q=%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%87%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%205-%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE.%20%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%E2%80%95%20%D0%93%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%E2%80%95%205%3A%200.%20%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%87%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%207-%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE&f=false) (олимпиады в Пекине, Лондоне):

**1/2 финала** (19.08): НИГЕРИЯ — БЕЛЬГИЯ — 4:1 (1:0); АРГЕНТИНА — БРАЗИЛИЯ — 3:0 (0:0).
**Матч за 3-е место**: ЮЖНАЯ КОРЕЯ — ЯПОНИЯ — 2:0 (1:0).
**ФИНАЛ**: МЕКСИКА — БРАЗИЛИЯ — 2:1 (1:0).

4. [Прочтение результата матча](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/452169/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B0/452170#452170) (наш сайт; никто не возражал по поводу оформления счёта):

*Какая боль, какая боль,

Аргентина — Ямайка — **5:0.***

5. Двоеточие как пунктуационный знак отбивается пробелом от следующего за ним слова.
   Двоеточие как знак деления отбивается пробелом с двух сторон.

Наше же двоеточие для обозначения счета нельзя отнести ни к пунктуации, ни к математике, поэтому считаю, что никакими пробелами его отделять не надо — как при обозначении времени (21:45; 08:07:23), как в шахматах (Лg2:g7).

В статье ["Спортивная типографика"](https://www.sports.ru/tribuna/blogs/sportsidentity/679189.html) имеется такая рекомендация: *Счёт пишется через двоеточие и не отбивается пробелами.*
А вот примеры оформления [счета на табло](https://www.google.com/search?source=univ&tbm=isch&q=%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE&fir=vSSW43cpctwvMM%252CNjjY1Izsd5gUmM%252C_%253BGQVrR2mXZtl8DM%252ClO403ai9NYM8DM%252C_%253BIWneHt9futub8M%252ChJOYXgcCQG1aoM%252C_%253BCEAuH9bW0IshAM%252CuYBFS5EbEmt-uM%252C_%253B9fa8-tTFDXeRvM%252CnwsLA73nCxoj9M%252C_%253BFCgxR7GUZMTxPM%252CD9OOYNTxUyIHYM%252C_%253BbHoeV3QG-Q3-JM%252ChJOYXgcCQG1aoM%252C_%253BFS1MYJHEoxhqkM%252C1p2kKuk0BQCfgM%252C_%253BQ_KOWx_mUmWBKM%252CZAoTp2RCFEkGpM%252C_%253BGquFO5LOXwNTXM%252CmJ56RTjjG5LAqM%252C_&usg=AI4_-kSgAHCDpAVKwZD2R5zc8pevIbCalA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjFtbCQpNv6AhUk-yoKHRD_C_YQjJkEegQICBAC&biw=1366&bih=657&dpr=1) (канадский похож на стилизацию "под табло" — разово, крупно и четко).

Comment: Тоже так считаю.

Comment: Угу, посмотрел спортивный канал, там в бегущих строках именно двоеточие без пробелов. Например: "Виннипег" — "Рейнджерс" — 4:1.

Comment: Спасибо еще раз, *Shi*, за принятие ответа. Думала, что "Аргентины — Ямайки" было достаточно. Оказалось — нет. Ну... тогда *отплюсовываю* дополнительно.

Answer (score 2):

Примеры газетного НКРЯ могут своим немалым количеством подтвердить то, что Справочная служба права в главном: пробелы нужны (как пробелы между знаками и цифрами). Но, делаются они только *после* символа (:), который является вариантом алгебраической нотации двоеточия; в речи часто озвучивается предлогами  *к*, *на*, *против*. В записях шахматных партий он обозначает взятие.

> У человека и машины счет равный 2,5: 2,5 [Е. Гик. Шахматы в
> художественной литературе // «Наука и жизнь», 2007].
>
> Впрочем, недолго: разделавшись с фарерским "Торсхваном" (2: 2, 4: 0),
> ГАК уступил дорогу голландскому "Утрехту" (3: 3, 0: 3) [Дмитрий
> Навоша, Юрий Дудь. «Известия», 2002.07.26].
>
> Пока счет 3: 1 в пользу «Динамо». [«Овечкин не сможет побить рекорд
> Гретцки» // Известия, 2019.03]
>
> Вышло же так, что Джокович умудрился сравнять счет — 5: 5. [Энди
> Маррей дождался своего // Коммерсант, 2012.09]